# How do I make a radial gradient with "rays" from the origin, not circles?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

Learning Illustrator, and I'm trying to find how to make a "radial" gradient that, rather than forming circles around the origin, creates "rays" from the origin:

[Example](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic.mhtml?id=185144417&src=lb-29971486)

I've got a similar button design, but can't seem to find the right method. Can't seem to find any tutorials either, but am not entirely sure what to search for.

Answer (score 7):

Create a circle and make it's stroke as wide as the circle itself. In the image I made a circle 100px wide, thus I made the stroke 100 px wide. I then set the stroke fill as a gradient.

[image]

Comment: I made two answers with different solutions to the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Using the Mesh tool with some tweaking will get you the desired results.

[image]