# Is it possible to realize this particular type of radial gradient in AI?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, illustrator-scripting

I came across a LaTeX package called [`pst-slpe`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-slpe/pst-slpe.pdf). It is part of the [PSTricks](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) bundle for generating ps graphics in LaTeX.

A particular type or gradient, called `radslope` (or `radslopes`) is defined in this `pst-slpe`, which looks like:
[image]

For some reason, I need to realize this in AI. It has to be vector graphics so PS is out of the window (live trace would not be a good idea). So my question is: is there a hidden function (that I am not aware of in this case) or a plugin or a script for AI that can realize this kind of gradient for me?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/40800/how-do-i-make-a-radial-gradient-with-rays-from-the-origin-not-circles?rq=1

Comment: @Scott Yeah, but I refer to pst-slpe, which is not mentioned in the original post. People who search pst-slpe will not find that post you have. Plus my figure looks better XD.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware about automatic option for that. But if you need this effect only for small task, so you can create it by yourself.

I've got the circle in 5 minutes, so if you play with options, probably you can create this on your own. I don't know if you need only square or circle is ok too. I've just copied the colors to gradient panel and applied this gradient to circle stroke with the parameters you can see on these screenshots:

[image]

and

[image]

The question was about gradient, so gradient you can create very easily. If you need some specific applications - you should state them in the question.

UPD

You can tweak the shape by creating some shape with no fill and huge external stroke and place it above the colored shape:

[image]

Comment: When I first learned Illustrator, this was the ONLY way to make gradients.

Comment: @Ilan Thank you. But this is not useful for my case. I have to deal with alot of irregular shapes too.

Comment: @TroyWoo I dont aware about "automation" of this effect, but I updated the answer with some tweak...

Comment: @Ilan Thank you for your effort. But that is still not what I wanted.